# Java calculate as double print as int

Tags: java

Let user input int and calculate as double and print as int.
I made this one but it would print as int. How can I fix this?

```
System.out.println("Please input integer a: ");
    double a = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please input integer b: ");
    double b = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please input integer c: ");
    double c = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please input integer d: ");
    double d = input.nextDouble();
    
    double result = a / b + c / d;
    
    System.out.println("Input a: " + a);
    System.out.println("Input b: " + b);
    System.out.println("Input c: " + c);
    System.out.println("Input d: " + d);
    
    System.out.println(" " + a + " " + c);
    System.out.println("--- + --- = " + result);
    System.out.println(" " + b + " " + d);
```

Comment: What are the inputs? What are the expected and actual outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [`Scanner.nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) and casting the ints into doubles only for the `result` calculation:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please input integer a: ");
    int a = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please input integer b: ");
    int b = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please input integer c: ");
    int c = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please input integer d: ");
    int d = input.nextInt();

    double result = (double) a / (double) b + (double) c / (double) d;

    System.out.println("Input a: " + a);
    System.out.println("Input b: " + b);
    System.out.println("Input c: " + c);
    System.out.println("Input d: " + d);

    int fractionBarABLength = Math.max(String.valueOf(a).length(), String.valueOf(b).length());
    String fractionBarAB = "-".repeat(fractionBarABLength);
    int fractionBarCDLength = Math.max(String.valueOf(c).length(), String.valueOf(d).length());
    String fractionBarCD = "-".repeat(fractionBarCDLength);

    String paddedA = String.format("%1$" + fractionBarABLength + "s", a);
    String paddedB = String.format("%1$" + fractionBarABLength + "s", b);
    String paddedC = String.format("%1$" + fractionBarCDLength + "s", c);
    String paddedD = String.format("%1$" + fractionBarCDLength + "s", d);

    System.out.printf("%s   %s%n", paddedA, paddedC);
    System.out.printf("%s + %s = %.2f%n", fractionBarAB, fractionBarCD, result);
    System.out.printf("%s   %s%n", paddedB, paddedD);
  }

}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Please input integer a: -1
Please input integer b: 2
Please input integer c: 3
Please input integer d: 4
Input a: -1
Input b: 2
Input c: 3
Input d: 4
-1   3
-- + - = 0.25
 2   4
```